# I am not able to remove legend in this google chart, also not able to change height , I putted it inside a col-md-4 div , also there help me

Tags: google-visualization, react-google-charts

**js code :**
its to add chart to col-4 bar must have 3 columns each having space between it all different color, remove legend in this google chart

```
function drawBarChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Retention", "Level", {
          role: "style"
        }],
        ["HIGH", 12, "#E54B4B"],
        ["ELEVATED", 29, "#FFB100"],
        ["LOW", 52, "#2BC18D"],

      ]);


      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        height: 600,
        width: 370,
        legend: 'none',
        bar: {
          groupWidth: "55%"
        },
        ticks: [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
      };



      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_divTwo'));
      // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(data, options));
    };
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be related to chart.js. Maybe you can remove the tag from the question

Comment: try --> `legend: {position: 'none'}`